# chop text from image using Aforge Histogram generated in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, histogram, aforge

I am developing text segmentation program in C#, I want to use histogram to segment text. How can I use histogram from aforge library? And I want to chop according threshold.
Still I developed only

```
verticalIntensityStatistics verticalintensity = new VerticalIntensityStatistics(bitmap);

Histogram histogram = verticalintensity.Gray;
```

Now how can chop text where histogram vally goes below threshold and make changes in original image.

Also I want to display this histogram on chart.

Answer (score 1):

I created a similar task.
You can take the histogram values: [Histogram.values](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/2bc82dff-4755-76a6-92b2-350a3dcf4798.htm)

The returning int [] have the same width (vertical projection) or heigth (horizontal projection) of the image.

Once you have the Int Array you can calculate, for example, the simple average value:

> int average = 0;
>
> Foreach (int elem in Array): average += elem;
>
> average = average / array.length;

So now you can iterate your array while the value is UNDER your average.

> int startWidth = 0;
>
> int endWidth = Array.lenght;
>
> while ( Array[ startWidth ] < average)    startWidth++;
>
> while ( Array[ endWidth ] < average)    endWidth--;
>
> //Here you have the new width that contains some text.
>
> //If you want segment the containing text you can iterate the code another time.
>
> //Until you get a single Word/Letter